# AbsListView.OnScrollListener vs RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

Tags: android, scroll, listener, android-recyclerview

Is `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` in `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` equivalent to `SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL` in `AbsListView.OnScrollListener` ?